# How to interact with a React element before it is loaded in the DOM in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, selenium

I am having issues interacting with a React element in Selenium due to it's conditionally rendered state. The specific element is a button nested within an iFrame (which I have switched the driver context to). This button switches to an 'inventory' tab in a React based extension overlay.

So far I have tried the following:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('react-tabs-2').click()")
```

and

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('tab-button')[1].click()")
```

Furthermore, instead of using client side JS, I have also tried to find by ID and click:

```
try:
    inventory_tab = driver.find_element_by_id('react-tabs-2')
    if inventory_tab != None:
        inventory_tab.click()
        time.sleep(3)
except Exception as e:
    print("Couldn't find inventory tab: " +str(e))
```

and finding all the possible 'tabs' to switch to and trying to print them:

```
try:
    print("Trying to find react tabs in iframe")
    react_tabs_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("react-tabs__tab-list")
    for elements in react_tabs_list:
        print(elements)
except:
    print("Error, couldn't find tab list.")
```

Both of the JS snippets I execute work once have already interacted with the inventory button (which I assume is due to the specific element then being loaded in the DOM).

The driver based snippets do not work due to this conditional rendering issue. They do however work if I manually click the inventory tab and switch back to another tab.

My question is, how can I interact with this inventory tab before it has been loaded/interacted with in the DOM? Surely there is a function call I can find or client side JS to execute which must handle this.

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused, can you interact with it or not? And no, you can't do anything with the element before it's in the DOM.

Comment: @Dmart I can click on the element myself yes. I can also use the code snippets provided to click on the element, however this only works after I have clicked on the element manually myself and it has loaded in the DOM, otherwise I get errors as the elements do not exist (even though I can clearly see the tab button in the UI).

Comment: So you need help with a locator of the inital element? Can you provide the HTML?